# PHP finds GMail messages from dev machine, but not live server

Tags: php, gmail, imap

I built a little script to run an end-to-end test of email sending within a Joomla website:

```
$testMailer =& JFactory::getMailer();

$testMailer->setSender(SENDER);
$testMailer->addReplyTo(SENDER);
$testMailer->addRecipient(TEST_EMAIL);

$subject = 'Automatic test '.md5(uniqid());

$testMailer->setSubject($subject);
$testMailer->setBody('This message is automatically retrieved. Please ignore.');

?>
<h2>Testing Joomla email sending functionality</h2><?php
flush();
if ($testMailer->Send() !== true) {
    echo '<p>ERROR - Mail Sending failed</p>';
}else{

    echo '<p>Email sent...</p>';
    flush();
    $sleep = 5;
    $progress = 0;
    $max = 300;
    set_time_limit($max+30);
    $found = 0;

    $mbox = imap_open(TEST_IMAP_SERVER, TEST_EMAIL, TEST_PASSWORD);

    if (!$mbox){
        echo '<p>ERROR - Login to '.TEST_EMAIL.' failed</p>';
        foreach (imap_errors() as $error){
            echo '<p>'.$error.'</p>';
        }
        die();
    }else{
        while (!$found && $progress < $max){

            $result = imap_search($mbox, 'SUBJECT "'.$subject.'"');

            foreach($result as $msgno) {
                $headers = imap_fetchheader($mbox, $msgno);
                if ($headers){
                    echo '<p>OK - EMail received</p>';
                    imap_delete($mbox,$msgno);
                    $found = 1;
                    die();
                }
            }
        }
        if (!$found){
            $progress+=$sleep;
            echo '<p>Waiting '.$sleep.' seconds to try again...('.$progress.' seconds total wait)</p>';
            flush();
            sleep($sleep);
        }
    }
    if (!$found){
        echo '<p>ERROR Giving up after '.$max.' seconds</p>';
    }
}
```

This script works fine from my loal development machine and consistently finds the message send.

The live site is on an Amazon EC2 server. At first, I had a warning of unusual login activity. I confirmed the script was known and reran in within 10 minutes.

Since then, the script can log in, but imap_search never finds any messages. They do however arrive in the inbox. The script on the dev site still works fine.

Telnet on the Amazon server is working as well

```
telnet imap.gmail.com 993
Trying 74.125.133.108...
Connected to gmail-imap.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please contact the vendor of that component if it supports the environment (Amazon EC2) you want to use it in.

Comment: @hakre - I have written this component.

Comment: Wow, then I'd say you must be the most versatile person to troubleshoot this. Maybe it wraps another library you didn't wrote? If so, contact the vendor of that library and check if it supports the environment.

Comment: Also it's not clear to me which kind of problem you describe. Are those different mail servers? Or just different boxes where the code is executed accessing the *same* mailserver? Also try to get error messages. That depends on the library you use internally.

Comment: The problem is happening when the script is run on a different server. Unfortunately no error messages, on one server, no messages are found on the other one they are always found.

Comment: Maybe the encoding of the text-string differs when you search and that might be the difference. Do a hex-dump of the search string and compare. Also compare versions of PHP and if you use a library of the library.

Comment: @jdog If you don't use `image_search`, can you read the messages? For example, try changing the `imap_search` statement to `$n = imap_num_msg($mbox);` and the `foreach` line to `for ($msgno = 0; $msgno < $n; $msgno++)`, just to see if the problem is related only  to the `imap_search` function.

Comment: @Enzine imap_header return false in every case.

Comment: @jdog If you run the script on the Amazon server with a different mail server (not Gmail), does it work?

Comment: On my local machine (Ubuntu 12.04) all of these work against a Courier IMAP server with my ISP: $result = imap_search($mbox, 'SUBJECT "'.$subject.'"'); $result = imap_search($mbox, 'UNDELETED');$n = imap_num_msg($mbox);

On the Amazon server (Ubuntu 10.04), none of the above work with Gmail, however $result = imap_search($mbox, 'UNDELETED'); works with  the Courier IMAP server.

Comment: @jdog I've made a test on my machine (Ubuntu 11.04) with my Gmail account and imap_search() is working. Did you check for errors in the Amazon web server log? Can you try to run the script from bash, just to be sure that you don't get any error? Try also enabling "display_errors" and set "error_reporting" to E_ALL in the Amazon server PHP.INI file.